# Combining two MySql queries into a single query based upon a condition

Tags: mysql, join, select, inner-join

I am using `5.7.20-enterprise-commercial` and have a MySql query which looks as below:

```
SELECT name FROM jobTable where jobId IN (SELECT dataId from logTable
WHERE eValue ='1098hbfce');
```

If the above query returns a null value then I want to run the below query:

```
SELECT name FROM jobTable where procId IN (
SELECT dataId from logTable WHERE eValue ='1098hbfce');
```

The only difference between first and second query is that in the first query `jobId` is used.
And, in the second query `procId` is used

Also, I don't want to run the second query if the first query returns `non null` value

I am using the following approach but it doesn't seem to working correctly

```
IF (SELECT name FROM jobTable where jobId IN (SELECT dataId from logTable
   WHERE eValue ='1098hbfce')) IS NOT NULL 
   EXECUTE (SELECT name FROM jobTable where procId IN (
   SELECT dataId from logTable WHERE eValue ='1098hbfce'));
```

The requirement is do it in the SQL query itself and without creating a stored procedure.
There is no relationship between `jobTable` and `logTable`

Comment: Looks familiar did you ask this yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT name 
FROM jobTable 
where (CASE 
       WHEN jobId IN (SELECT dataId from logTable WHERE eValue ='1098hbfce')
       THEN 1
       WHEN procId IN (SELECT dataId from logTable WHERE eValue ='1098hbfce') 
       THEN 1 
      END) = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Coalesce ON

```
drop table if exists t,log_table;
create table t(name varchar(10),jobid int,procid int);
create table log_table(dataid int,evalue varchar(10));

insert into t values ('aaa',null,null),('bbb',null,1),('ccc',1,null);
insert into log_table values(1,'1098hbfce');

select *,
        coalesce(jobid,procid),
        coalesce(procid,jobid)
        
from t
join log_table lt on 
        dataid = coalesce(jobid,procid) or dataid = coalesce(procid,jobid)  ;

+------+-------+--------+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------------+
| name | jobid | procid | dataid | evalue    | coalesce(jobid,procid) | coalesce(procid,jobid) |
+------+-------+--------+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------------+
| bbb  |  NULL |      1 |      1 | 1098hbfce |                      1 |                      1 |
| ccc  |     1 |   NULL |      1 | 1098hbfce |                      1 |                      1 |
+------+-------+--------+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```